# How to toggle Angular Material mat-card to full screen

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to emulate a portal style page using Angular Material, that shows a grid of cards, and each card should be expandable to take up the container (i.e. most of the visible page). All the other cards are covered (not visible) when 1 card is expanded. The cards have state/data, which is mostly contained in the card's component currently.

I'm looking for a good design to support this. My initial thought was that I could use the same component in two places, once as full screen, once as the content of a card, combined with ngIf to show or hide the components. But I think for this to work, I would have to keep the data outside of the components, in services, and I was trying to avoid making this change. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Should be possible using CSS , however imo You should use `MatDialog` instead for displaying expanded contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a template card and bind selected card data to it. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-techws-gnm5eh)

Comment: Ehsan, thanks! I've been away from this for a while, but that would work.

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time working on it and an easy solution is to toggle an additional class on the card based on some condition. I.e.:

`<mat-card [ngClass]="{'fullscreen': isCardExpanded}"></mat-card>`

```
.mat-card {
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.fullscreen {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Have a look at this [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-techws).

Comment: That looks good, but I'm not sure if it would work in the situation where there are multipe cards (say a grid of cards in grid-list or flexbox), and you want to hide all the other cards, and full screen the original card?

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm actually having the same problem myself now. I think the way to go is to dynamically assign and remove classes based on some conditions, which will then take care of hiding all the cards except the one that needs to be maximised. I'll update the answer when I get to a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure CSS method

`<mat-card class="card">`

In your CS file include

```
.card{
  position:fixed;
  min-height:100%;
  max-height:100%;      
 }
```